# Select row one by one based on hierarchy using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
SampleID | MemberId | MemberType | Status    | ExpDate
       1 |      222 | AA         | Active    | NULL
       2 |      222 | AA         | Pending   | NULL
       3 |      222 | AA         | Cancelled | 2014-06-04 13:35:04.267
       4 |      333 | AA         | Pending   | NULL
       5 |      333 | AA         | Cancelled | 2014-06-04 13:35:04.267
       6 |      444 | AA         | Cancelled | 2014-06-04 13:35:04.267
```

In the above table there are 3 rows for Member ID 222 with multiple status like Active, Pending and Cancelled.
If `MemberId` has more that one status I need to order them having Active first, then Pending, and Cancelled last. The order should stand even if not all the status value are there.

Comment: I did not get any error but I get all three rows for MemberID 222. But I want to have active row first, if the member have only pending and cancelled status the Pending first else cancelled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with CASE for `Status` in ORDER BY class:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (
   SELECT T.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID
                          ORDER BY CASE Status 
                                    WHEN 'Active' THEN 1
                                    WHEN 'Pending' THEN 2
                                    WHEN 'Cancelled' THEN 3
                                   END ) as RN
    FROM T) as T1
WHERE RN=1
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/66ace/5)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a subquery using a case for the status and append a number to the status as 1. Active, 2. Pending, 3. Cancelled since they are not alphabetical, and then you can do a max on the status to get what you want.

Lidia D.

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution but may be it is somehow dull

if you can update your table so as to concatenate status with number at first depending on it's periority like this

```
SampleID MemberId MemberType Status ExpDate
1 222 AA 3Active NULL
2 222 AA 2Pending NULL
3 222 AA 1Cancelled 2014-06-04 13:35:04.267
4 333 AA 2Pending NULL
5 333 AA 1Cancelled 2014-06-04 13:35:04.267
6 444 AA 1Cancelled 2014-06-04 13:35:04.267
```

now you can group by selecting the max(status)

```
select memberid, right(max(status),len(max(status))-1)
from yourtable
group by memberid
```

P.S. you can use case statement to update status column in order to concatunate number at beginning